# How to json encode foreach in PHP with Google Drive API

Tags: php, json, datatable, google-drive-api

I'm having a problem when I use ajax and using foreach with google drive api

PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#example").on('click', '.checklist', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var id2 = e.target.getAttribute('data-id'); 
    
    
    $('.filelist').DataTable({
        destroy : true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "get_files_json.php", 
            "type" : "POST",
            "data": { 'folder_id': id2 },
            "dataSrc": ""    
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id_folder" }
        ],
        "order": [
        [ 0, 'asc' ]
        
        ]           
    });
  });
});
```

JSON File:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setAuthConfig('gdrive/json/'. $_SESSION['json'] . '.json');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setSubject($_SESSION['json_email']);
$client->setAccessType('offline');  
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($GLOBALS['client']);
                        
        $idfolder = $_POST['folder_id'];
        $parameters2['pageSize'] = 1000;
        $parameters2['orderBy'] = "modifiedTime desc";
        $parameters2['q'] = "mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '$idfolder' in parents";
        $parameters2['fields'] = 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType,size,webContentLink,webViewLink), nextPageToken'; 
        $sub_files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters2);
            
$data = array(); //create empty array

   foreach($sub_files as $kk => $sub_file) {

     $data[] = array(
            "id_folder" => $sub_file['name']
        );//assign each sub-array to the newly created array
  } 
 echo json_encode($data);
```

error message:

"DataTables warning: table id=filelist - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error"

Comment: Im confused thats not a json file thasts a php script.

Comment: @DaImTo I just turn the php to json. if that's the right term? I'm kinda newbie when it comes to this sir sorry :)

Comment: Where are you encountering this error? I don't think `$sub_files` is an array. Have you checked whether you get the actual list of files from Drive when you apply the changes specified in your answer? I think you should use `getFiles()` to retrieve the list of files https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_FileList.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after many hours of trying and test I found a solution.

I just put

```
   @
```

in my

```
   $sub_files
```

variable

Answer:

```
   @$sub_files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters2);
```